# Generate range of promotion codes that are not guessable

Tags: java, security, promotion-code

I'm looking for a way to generate a range of promotion codes. It would be trivial if it wasn't for both these requirements. That it needs to be a range (not saving every single promotion code in a database) to make it fast and that it is not guessable so it can not generate codes like this 000-000-001, 000-000-002, 000-000-003... and so on.

Is there an algorithm to solve this problem? I could try to solve it with some sort of hashing but trying to solve this security problem myself might leave the service open to exploits that I didn't think about.

Comment: If they are in a range, they are guessable.

Comment: Append a HMAC at the end.

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708559/coupon-code-generation

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the question was just edited. Look at the initial version. And honestly, I still consider it to be too broad, respectively a mere requirement dump without any own efforts.

Comment: There is. 000-000-001, 000-000-002 doesn't work for him.

Comment: Does range imply sequence?  I'm not certain what is being asked here.

Comment: By range, I mean being able to refer to one database record for every code in the range to find out if it exist or not. So if the range contained 1 million code there would be one row in the database and not 1 million rows.

Comment: What does "not guessable" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first requirement (not saving every promotional code in a database) is problematic.

The question is, is it allowed to redeem a single promotional code multiple times?

If this is not allowed then you have to store the already redeemed codes in some persistent data store anyway, so why not store the generated codes in the persistent data store from the beginning, together with a flag indicating whether it has been redeemed or not?

---

If you don't want to store all codes / can't store all codes, you could still use a `Random` with a seed unique to your current campaign:

```
long seed = 20190921065347L; // identifies your current campaign
Random r = new Random(seed);
for (int i = 0; i < numCodes; i++) {
    System.out.println(r.nextLong());
}
```

or

```
long seed = 20190921065347L; // identifies your current campaign
Random r = new Random(seed);
r.longs(numCodes, 100_000_000_000_000L, 1_000_000_000_000_000L)
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

To find out whether a code is valid you can generate the same codes again:

```
long seed = 20190921065347L; // identifies your current campaign
Random r = new Random(seed);
System.out.println(
    r.longs(numCodes, 100_000_000_000_000L, 1_000_000_000_000_000L)
     .anyMatch(l -> l == 350160558695557L));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```java
      Random r = new Random();
      long start = 1_000_000_000;
      long end = 10_000_000_000L;

      long n = r.longs(1, start, end).reduce(0, (a, b) -> b);
      String s = String.format("%,d", n).replace(",", "-");
      System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Not really, it doesn't solve both problems. Sure it is not guessable but how would you store the range and not every individual code.

Comment: So you want to get the same code from the range, using the range to protect the actual code?  If that is correct, why not store a SHA hash representation of the code?  Then when someone enters the code you just run the SHA algorithm to see if it matches.  Of course, that is not very fast.  And just to be clear (if it isn't already) I may not be fully understanding your requirements.